# Runtime.getRuntime() does not provide output in server

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, runtime, server

I am trying to calculate the runtime memory usage by this stub. This is working fine in eclipse but when I run the same code on linux server, it doesn't print anything but 0.
**Server configuration:**
64-bit,
4 core server,
15GB RAM

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long total1 = (runTime.totalMemory()) - (runTime.freeMemory());
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    Object nee = new Object();
    objList.add(nee);
}
long total2 = (runTime.totalMemory()) - (runTime.freeMemory());
System.out.println("total memory consumed : " + (total2 - total1));
```

getting some value for generating 2.5m objects but nothing is shown for anything lower number of objects.

As per my understanding ,the server is having some "precision" for memory calculation.
       Means, there will be no change in the value of the calculated memory till memory consumption doesn't crosses this "precision" value.

Now ,doubt is how this precision value is determined and is it configurable??

Answer (score 2):

It's common practice on servers to redirect the output stream away from the console, because there frequently isn't one.  Speak with the server admin and check if it's going to /dev/null, a log file or something similar.